# How do I mention a thread in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am using discord.py and I need to mention a thread, so it would look like this:
[image]

In **pycord**, I could do `thread.mention`, here's the code snippet for **pycord**

```
class Example:
    @app_commands.command(name="chat", description="some desc")
    async def chat(self, ctx, msg):
                await ctx.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
                thread = await self.bot.fetch_channel(user_thread[1])
                await ctx.respond(f"Hello {ctx.author.mention}\nThread: {thread.mention}",
                                  ephemeral=True)
```

It doesn't work in **discord.py,** but I want to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score -1):

In discord.py you can select it from the built-in threads list, like this:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="mention")
async def mention(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    thread = interaction.guild.threads[0]
    await interaction.response.send_message(thread.mention)
```